# How to get the language value from $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] using PHP?

Tags: php, regex, http, localization, internationalization

```
<?php
$language = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
echo $language;
?>
```

When I use Firefox to test this block of code, I get `en-us,en;q=0.7,ja;q=0.3`,

when I use IE to test the block of code, I get `zh-cn`.

Is the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` a string? How to determine whether the preferred language is Chinese or Japanese? How can I write a regular expression to get the language from the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']`?

Comment: I just want to get the language which has the highest priority.

Comment: OR: user function from wordpres plugin: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_multilingual-and-http_accept_language

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` is a string -- see [`$_SERVER`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Its content is sent by the browser -- which explains why you get different results depending on the browser you are using : most likely, your Firefox is configured to request pages in english *(high priority)* or japanese *(low priority)*, while your IE is configured to request pages in chinese.

This is because that HTTP header can contain :

- a list of languages
- optionnaly, with region codes
- with associated priorities.

The idea being that the server should respond, using the language that suits "the best" what's requested by the user.

About parsing that header, this blog-post might be a interesting read : [Parse Accept-Language to detect a user's language](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/use-accept-language-header)

There is a portion of code proposed to parse that HTTP header -- and it generates an array that looks like this *(quoting)* :

```
Array
(
    [en-ca] => 1
    [en] => 0.8
    [en-us] => 0.6
    [de-de] => 0.4
    [de] => 0.2
)
```

Which is an array of languages, sorted by priority, in descending order -- which is probably what you want.

Comment: This method is complicated. I want a simple solution. I just want to detect Japanese, Chinese and English. I treat en-ca and en-us the same, just English.

Comment: Maybe I can use strpos, I will try it.

Comment: +1 even 10 years after it was written the code in that blog post is still the best method, utterly ridiculous there is no suitable built-in in PHP

Answer (score 7):

As of v5.3 PHP has function for that purpose:

```
$locale = locale_accept_from_http($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/locale.acceptfromhttp.php

Answer (score 4):

I just use 
    `explode(",",$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])` to get the first possible language that my client might use. It works fine on chrome and IE 10. Not sure if it would be wrong on other browsers.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
function getUserBaseLanguage() {
    global $_SERVER;
    $accept_languages           = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
    $accept_languages_arr       = explode(",",$accept_languages);
    foreach($accept_languages_arr as $accept_language) {
        preg_match ("/^(([a-zA-Z]+)(-([a-zA-Z]+)){0,1})(;q=([0-9.]+)){0,1}/" , $accept_language, $matches );
        if (!$matches[6]) $matches[6]=1;
        $result[$matches[1]] = array(
            'lng_base'  => $matches[2],
            'lng_ext'   => $matches[4],
            'lng'       => $matches[1],
            'priority'  => $matches[6],
            '_str'      => $accept_language,
        );
    }
    return $result;
}

print_r(getUserBaseLanguage());
```

output:

```
Array
(
[pl] => Array
    (
        [lng_base] => pl
        [lng_ext] => 
        [lng] => pl
        [priority] => 1
        [_str] => pl
    )

[en-US] => Array
    (
        [lng_base] => en
        [lng_ext] => US
        [lng] => en-US
        [priority] => 0.7
        [_str] => en-US;q=0.7
    )

[en] => Array
    (
        [lng_base] => en
        [lng_ext] => 
        [lng] => en
        [priority] => 0.3
        [_str] => en;q=0.3
    )

)
```