# change the page on certain language

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a website for both English and German audience. I thought it would be easy to find a code snippet that checks browser language and reloads another page – only if the browser language is German, all other languages stay with the English page. But I could not find any such thing. As my own programming skills are very lacking, I am a designer, not a programmer, I hope someone might help me out here?

The website consists of only two pages, index.html (English) and index-deutsch.html (German). I have already jquery in use with ilightbox and royalslider. PHP would also be an option.

Thom

Comment: I find it fascinating how the lack of programming corresponds with the lack of being able to use the search function. maybe a designer thing? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770513/detect-browser-language-in-php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803702/auto-detect-language-and-redirect-user

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called i18n. Here is a [library](https://github.com/Philipp15b/php-i18n) for the same. This would also help you in future if you decide you want to support more languages