# PHP Detect User language

Tags: php

I need a script like

```
if ($userLanguage === 'english') {
  echo "we have detected you are English. would you like to visit our site in English?";
} else {
  header('location: /index.php?lang=default');
}
```

The script above is used for an example. I have looked all over google and all it gave me was geolocation scripts and such. I don't want a third party URL in my script. You never know if their service goes down or not.

Where do I find something like this?

Comment: If you're developing a site of any size or scope you're going to have to come to rely on third-party sources at some point.

Comment: It is impossible to reliably "detect" the users language. Many reasons for this. I suggest you check the http request headers for the "preferred language".

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not going to repeat all the valid answers here, but [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6038460/4960774) shows another good approach (for multi-lingo websites) taking advantage of [`http_negotiate_language() method`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-negotiate-language.php) <sup>[*mirror*](https://web.archive.org/web/20150623034838/http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-negotiate-language.php)</sup>

So combining that mapping and your exciting code you will have:

```
$map = array("en" => "english", "es" => "spanish");
$userLanguage = $map[ http_negotiate_language(array_keys($map)) ];

if ($userLanguage === 'english') {
  echo "we have detected you are English. would you like to visit our site in English?";
} else {
  header('location: /index.php?lang=default');
}
```

But if you are only interested to detect the english (**en**) language, you might want to shorten the script to:

```
if ('en' == substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2)) {
  echo "we have detected you are English. would you like to visit our site in English?";
} else {
  header('location: /index.php?lang=default');
}
```

Comment: Strangely enough, the php.net documentation for `http_negotiate_language()` doesn't exist anymore. Haven't researched the *why*

Answer (score 0):

i would do something like this:

```
<?php
$language = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
switch ($language){
    case "sv":
        include("index_swedish.php");
        break;
    case "nl":
        include("index_dutch.php");
        break; 
    default:
        include("index_english.php"); // or do what ever you want
        break;

}
?>
```

Here is a list of [browser language codes](http://www.metamodpro.com/browser-language-codes)

Comment: That http header might contain more than a single language.

Comment: Change of plans, is it possible to detect if the user is not from netherlands (NL)? E.g. if you're german, you will get an popup that you can view the site in English and so on with every country but the netherlands. Is that possible?

Comment: Added a default case to the code, it should do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

yes the idea is good, try the short one also,

```
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
header("location: ".$lang."/index.php");
```

Comment: Consider a default for clients that don't pass `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
if ($lang == 'en') {
 echo "we have detected you are English. would you like to visit our site in English?";
} 
else {
  header("location: /index.php?lang=default");
}
```