# Redirect an Index Page Request before the Default Page has been loaded?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cookies, http-redirect

I have the following scenario. I have a wordpress site running. 
The site has the following urls:

```
www.example.com
www.example.com/siteA
www.example.com/siteB
www.example.com/de
www.example.com/de/siteA
www.example.com/de/siteB
```

My wordpress site has a language switcher, which creates a cookie, when a language is set. 
I want to achieve the following. When a user visits the site `www.example.com` for the first time the server will get the request for `www.example.com` the server should then send a minimal code (not the default index page) that checks the cookie and the browser language preferences. If the cookie is set take the language value from there. If not, take the language value from the browser setting. Send a request to the server and request the page that fits best for the user. 
For example, if the language value is set to `de` request the page `www.example.com/de`.

I want to prevent that I have to load the entire index page two times. First in the default language, English, and after that in the specific language, German. Therefore I need a way to add only minimal code in the first request response.

**How can I redirect an Index Page Request before the Default Page has been loaded?**

Answer (score 0):

Check out this for discussion on how to get the language:  [Using the PHP HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE server variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038236/using-the-php-http-accept-language-server-variable)

To redirect:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/siteA');
```