# PHP- Get current locale

Tags: php

I am setting the locale of the website using this function:

```
function set_locale($locale) { // ie. en, es

    $language = $locale;
    putenv("LANG=".$language); 
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $language);
    $domain = "phd";
    bindtextdomain($domain, "locale"); 
    bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');

    textdomain($domain);

} // end set_locale
```

When someone visits the site, they have the ability to change their locale. What I am trying to do is somewhere else in the site retrieve what the current locale is.

How would I do this?

Comment: save it in a session?

Comment: dunno why u are using putenv, but to retrieve it simply use getenv()

Comment: What is the scope of this configuration?  Are you allowing them to set it for the duration of the connection?  Are you looking for a permanent set?  Or are you trying to dynamically determine their locale?

Comment: They click a link with a GET variable like `?do=locale&lang=en` and each page checks for those GET variables and if set, will run through this function.

Comment: Try taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316476/how-to-get-the-language-value-from-serverhttp-accept-language-using-php

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can call setlocale like so, and it'll return the current local.

```php
$currentLocale = setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);
echo $currentLocale; //outputs C/en_US.UTF-8/C/C/C/C on my machine
```

Here is documentation from php.net as commented by @JROB

> locale
>
> If locale is "0", the locale setting is not affected, only the current setting is returned.
>
> If locale is NULL or the empty string "", the locale names will be set from the values of environment variables with the same names as the above categories, or from "LANG".
>
> If locale is an array or followed by additional parameters then each array element or parameter is tried to be set as new locale until success. This is useful if a locale is known under different names on different systems or for providing a fallback for a possibly not available locale.

Comment: To clarify, I've posted this from php.net: `setlocale (int $category, string $locale)`. If locale is "0", the locale setting is not affected, only the current setting is returned.

Comment: See also [localeconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.localeconv.php) to get numeric formats.

Comment: Update for PHP 8.0+. I use `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US');` but `setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);` return just `C`.

Comment: Sorry, I found the problem now. ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/70312801/128761 )

Answer (score 11):

Another answer after two years!

You can simply user `Locale::getDefault()` or `locale_get_default()` to get the current locale.

http://php.net/manual/en/locale.getdefault.php

Intl `Locale` class is the modern alternative for old functions. Once you started using it, you need to update the local by php.net/manual/en/locale.setdefault.php function

Comment: No it doesn't. It gets the *default* locale, not the *current* locale. The default locale is not by definition the same as the current locale. When you're switching between locales, setlocale(LC_WHATEVER, 0) is still the way to retrieve the current locale.

Comment: You are again referring to the *default* locale which is, as I already said, not by definition the same as the *current* locale.

Comment: Code generating documents with different locales, using for example strftime. It’s not possible to pass a locale to strftime, so the locale needs to be changed temporarily. I know the intl module could be used for date/time formatting, but still there are lots of functions in php relying on the current locale. Even the conversion from a float to a string uses the current locale. As such, the default locale is not always helpful when you’re doing i18n stuff and need to switch between different locales.

Comment: This also not working on all machine. I got "Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function locale_get_default" error.

Comment: @vee, you need to install intl extension first

Comment: Why are you still notifying ME about this?

Comment: Despite the discussion on whether it returns default or current locale, `locale_get_default()` did return whatever I had set with `setlocale()` previously, so I guess this answer is the best one.