# What localization does browser support?

Tags: localization

What spoken languages does browser support?
Is there a list some where?

This may not be the best approach, but I am think that if I use:

```
 $_SERVER('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE');
```

To get the language that the browser is set to, then I can let the page content be created by data from the database.

The thing I need to know is what does $_SERVER('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE') actually return, in the form of languages. Is there a list some where?

Comment: Your question is not really clear, but my guess is that you are looking for information that has been provided [in this answer...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316476/how-to-get-the-language-value-from-serverhttp-accept-language-using-php). Or you are looking for a list of ISO 639 language codes?

Comment: That is a very similar question, but what I need is what values can be expected, for example "en-ca,en;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.6,de-de;q=0.4,de;q=0.2". It is easy enough to get the value, but what values can be returned, is there a list somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Language codes are based on [RFC 4646](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4646), and a somewhat dated list has been published [here](http://www.metamodpro.com/browser-language-codes) - it covers quite a few languages, so maybe it is enough for your immediate needs. Language codes are based on ISO 639-1 language codes and ISO 3166-1 country codes, both of which are subject to change. Any list that you build up will be outdated as soon as one of these two standards is modified.

A more detailed explanation of language codes can be found at [mozilla](https://wiki.mozilla.org/L10n:Locale_Codes).